# Passing container name as a parameter to BlobTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have a little C# app that does some stuff when a new blob is added to a container in a storage account.

I'm working locally using Visual Studio 2017.

The VS template gives me:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LogicAppTriggerFunction
{
    public static class BlobTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobTrigger")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to replace `"samples-workitems"` with a variable that relates to the name of my container. I only want to work with one container, but I don't want to "hard code" it.

If I am on the right lines, this setting is stored in `function.json` that is built at compile-time. When working locally, I think / thought that the contents of `function.json` is read by `local.settings.json`, however I now believe that to be for appSettings.json.

Reading the MS doco, particularly on [trigger bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings), it looks like `myContainer/{name}` should be read from function.json. I understand that function.json is built dynamically and shouldn't be modified.

I have tried various methods that I know to essentially replace the string `myContainer/{name}`, but they all result in the error:

```
[20/08/2018 14:56:36] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'TriggerLogicApp.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Invalid blob trigger path '{container}/{name}'. Container paths cannot contain {resolve} tokens.
```

I believe what I need to do is "create" (or update) the `path` value in `function.json`, programatically, but I can't find out how to do this.

Can anyone shed any light on what I need to do and possibly how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Specify your container name in `local.settings.json` locally or in Application settings on Azure.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        ....
        "MyBlobContainer":"samples-workitems"
    }
}
```

In your function signature, use [App setting binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings) wrapped in percent signs.

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("%MyBlobContainer%/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jerry Liu. Your solution is what I needed. Why MS docs couldn't say that...

Comment: what about parametrizing it using pipeline?

Comment: @woter324 check [here (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns)

Comment: As addition to jerry's answer, you can also reference to nested values using colons, like "%JobOptions:ContainerName%"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a BlobTrigger, have you considered using the [EventGridTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid)?

Your function will receive subscribed events from the `Storage Accounts` topic, and will need logic to ignore/discard uninteresting events, but the upside is that you will receive the full URL of the storage container in either the `subject` or the events' `data.url` structure.

Here's what that structure looks like (from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid)):

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/eg0122/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/egblobstore",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/{containername}/blobs/blobname.jpg",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2018-01-23T17:02:19.6069787Z",
  "id": "{guid}",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "{guid}",
    "requestId": "{guid}",
    "eTag": "0x8D562831044DDD0",
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "contentLength": 2248,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://egblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}/blobname.jpg",
    "sequencer": "000000000000272D000000000003D60F",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "{guid}"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

Comment: Thank you @josh E. This function triggers a logic app and as I am only working with one container, I haven't investigated EventGrid yet. I will do in version 2.0.